# 500 - array_key_exists(): Argument #1 ($key)laravel file manager

Tags: php, laravel

> array_key_exists(): Argument #1 ($key) must be a valid array offset type.

When I try to integrate the file manager, the condition that if the user has the id == 1 does not show certain disks on the list but generates that error and I am following the documentation as is

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Alexusmai\LaravelFileManager\Services\ConfigService\ConfigRepository;

class TestConfigRepository implements ConfigRepository
{
    // implement all methods from interface
    
    /**
     * Get disk list
     *
     * ['public', 'local', 's3']
     *
     * @return array
     */
    

    final public function getRoutePrefix(): string
    {
        return config('file-manager.routePrefix');
    }

   final public function getDiskList(): array
    {

        if (\Auth::id() === 1) {
            return [
                ['public'],
            ];
        }
        
        return ['public'];
    }

    final public function getLeftDisk(): ?string
    {
        return config('file-manager.leftDisk');
    }

    final public function getRightDisk(): ?string
    {
        return config('file-manager.rightDisk');
    }

    /**
     * Default path for left manager
     *
     * null - root directory
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    final public function getLeftPath(): ?string
    {
        return config('file-manager.leftPath');
    }

    /**
     * Default path for right manager
     *
     * null - root directory
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    final public function getRightPath(): ?string
    {
        return config('file-manager.rightPath');
    }

    /**
     * Image cache ( Intervention Image Cache )
     *
     * set null, 0 - if you don't need cache (default)
     * if you want use cache - set the number of minutes for which the value should be cached
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    final public function getCache(): ?int
    {
        return config('file-manager.cache');
    }

    /**
     * File manager modules configuration
     *
     * 1 - only one file manager window
     * 2 - one file manager window with directories tree module
     * 3 - two file manager windows
     *
     * @return int
     */
    final public function getWindowsConfig(): int
    {
        return config('file-manager.windowsConfig');
    }

    /**
     * File upload - Max file size in KB
     *
     * null - no restrictions
     */
    final public function getMaxUploadFileSize(): ?int
    {
        return config('file-manager.maxUploadFileSize');
    }

    /**
     * File upload - Allow these file types
     *
     * [] - no restrictions
     */
    final public function getAllowFileTypes(): array
    {
        return config('file-manager.allowFileTypes');
    }

    /**
     * Show / Hide system files and folders
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    final public function getHiddenFiles(): bool
    {
        return config('file-manager.hiddenFiles');
    }

    /**
     * Middleware
     *
     * Add your middleware name to array -> ['web', 'auth', 'admin']
     * !!!! RESTRICT ACCESS FOR NON ADMIN USERS !!!!
     *
     * @return array
     */
    final public function getMiddleware(): array
    {
        return config('file-manager.middleware');
    }

    /**
     * ACL mechanism ON/OFF
     *
     * default - false(OFF)
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    final public function getAcl(): bool
    {
        return config('file-manager.acl');
    }

    /**
     * Hide files and folders from file-manager if user doesn't have access
     *
     * ACL access level = 0
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    final public function getAclHideFromFM(): bool
    {
        return config('file-manager.aclHideFromFM');
    }

    /**
     * ACL strategy
     *
     * blacklist - Allow everything(access - 2 - r/w) that is not forbidden by the ACL rules list
     *
     * whitelist - Deny anything(access - 0 - deny), that not allowed by the ACL rules list
     *
     * @return string
     */
    final public function getAclStrategy(): string
    {
        return config('file-manager.aclStrategy');
    }

    /**
     * ACL rules repository
     *
     * default - config file(ConfigACLRepository)
     *
     * @return string
     */
    final public function getAclRepository(): string
    {
        return config('file-manager.aclRepository');
    }

    /**
     * ACL Rules cache
     *
     * null or value in minutes
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    final public function getAclRulesCache(): ?int
    {
        return config('file-manager.aclRulesCache');
    }

    /**
     * Whether to slugify filenames
     *
     * boolean
     *
     * @return bool|null
     */
    final public function getSlugifyNames(): ?bool
    {
        return config('file-manager.slugifyNames', false);
    }

   
    
}
```

```php
<?php

use Alexusmai\LaravelFileManager\Services\ConfigService\DefaultConfigRepository;
use Alexusmai\LaravelFileManager\Services\ACLService\ConfigACLRepository;

return [

    /**
     * Establecer configuración del repositorio 
     *
     * Predeterminado: DefaultConfigRepository obtener configuración de este archivo
     */
    'configRepository'  => DefaultConfigRepository::class,

    /**
     * Repositorio de reglas de ACL
     *
     * Predeterminado - ConfigACLRepository (ver reglas en - aclRules)
     */
    'aclRepository'     => ConfigACLRepository::class,

    //********* Default configuration for DefaultConfigRepository **************

    /**
     * LFM Route prefix
     * !!! WARNING - if you change it, you should compile frontend with new prefix(baseUrl) !!!
     */
    'routePrefix'       => 'file-manager',

    /**
     * List of disk names that you want to use
     * (from config/filesystems)
     */
    'diskList' => ['public'/*,'Ambiental','Acabado','Calidad','Corte-Curvado','Compras',
'Costos-Comercial','Direc-Produc','Gerencia'*/,'Ingenieria'/*,'Logistica','Mantenimiento','Metrologia','Coor-Produc','RR.HH','SG-SST','SGC','Soldadura','Troquelado','Vulcanizado'*/],

    /**
     * Disco predeterminado para el administrador izquierdo
     *
     * nulo: selecciona automáticamente el primer disco en la lista de discos
     */
    'leftDisk'          => null,

    /**
     * Disco predeterminado para el administrador derecho
     *
     * nulo: selecciona automáticamente el primer disco en la lista de discos
     */
    'rightDisk'         => null,

    /**
     * Default path for left manager
     *
     * null - root directory
     */
    'leftPath'          => null,

    /**
     * Default path for right manager
     *
     * null - root directory
     */
    'rightPath'         => null,

    /**
     * Image cache ( Intervention Image Cache )
     *
     * set null, 0 - if you don't need cache (default)
     * if you want use cache - set the number of minutes for which the value should be cached
     */
    'cache'             => null,

    /**
     * Configuración de los módulos del administrador de archivos
     *
     * 1 - solo una ventana del administrador de archivos
     * 2 - una ventana del administrador de archivos con módulo de árbol de directorios
     * 3 - dos ventanas del administrador de archivos
     */
    'windowsConfig'     => 2,

    /**
     * File upload - Max file size in KB
     *
     * null - no restrictions
     */
    'maxUploadFileSize' => null,

    /**
     * File upload - Allow these file types
     *
     * [] - no restrictions
     */
    'allowFileTypes'    => [],

    /**
     * Show / Hide system files and folders
     */
    'hiddenFiles'       => true,

    /***************************************************************************
     * Middleware
     *
     * Add your middleware name to array -> ['web', 'auth', 'admin']
     * !!!! RESTRICT ACCESS FOR NON ADMIN USERS !!!!
     */
    'middleware'        => ['web'],

    /***************************************************************************
     * ACL mechanism ON/OFF
     *
     * default - false(OFF)
     */
    'acl'               => false,

    /**
     * Hide files and folders from file-manager if user doesn't have access
     *
     * ACL access level = 0
     */
    'aclHideFromFM'     => true,

    /**
     * ACL strategy
     *
     * blacklist - Allow everything(access - 2 - r/w) that is not forbidden by the ACL rules list
     *
     * whitelist - Deny anything(access - 0 - deny), that not allowed by the ACL rules list
     */
    'aclStrategy'       => 'blacklist',

    /**
     * ACL Rules cache
     *
     * null or value in minutes
     */
    'aclRulesCache'     => null,

    //********* Default configuration for DefaultConfigRepository END **********


    /***************************************************************************
     * ACL rules list - used for default ACL repository (ConfigACLRepository)
     *
     * 1 it's user ID
     * null - for not authenticated user
     *
     * 'disk' => 'disk-name'
     *
     * 'path' => 'folder-name'
     * 'path' => 'folder1*' - select folder1, folder12, folder1/sub-folder, ...
     * 'path' => 'folder2/*' - select folder2/sub-folder,... but not select folder2 !!!
     * 'path' => 'folder-name/file-name.jpg'
     * 'path' => 'folder-name/*.jpg'
     *
     * * - wildcard
     *
     * access: 0 - deny, 1 - read, 2 - read/write
     */
    'aclRules'          => [
        null => [
            //['disk' => 'public', 'path' => '/', 'access' => 2],
        ],
        1    => [
            //['disk' => 'public', 'path' => 'images/arch*.jpg', 'access' => 2],
            //['disk' => 'public', 'path' => 'files/*', 'access' => 1],
        ],
    ],

    /**
     * Enable slugification of filenames of uploaded files.
     *
     */
    'slugifyNames'      => false,
];
```

It's all the code I have

I have tried to consult, continue seeing the documentation attached the link I have tried to change the code in several ways but none have worked it keeps throwing the same error
https://github.com/alexusmai/laravel-file-manager/blob/master/config/file-manager.php

Comment: `'aclRules' => [null => [`. This might be your issue. I'm don't think null is a valid array key

Comment: yes of course, the problem is that I am not yet integrating any of the acl

Comment: @santiagoalarcon so... then there you go, that is the issue... I do not see the point of this question...

Comment: Yes, of course, why include it, since for it to run it asks to show all the methods of the interface and that is one, and if I replace public function getDiskList(): array
    {
        if (\Authentication::id() === 1) {
            return [
                ['public', 'local', 's3'],
            ];
        }
        
        return['public'];
    } by return config('file-manager.diskList'); by return config('file-manager.diskList'); The program works excellent but I don't have the conditional for the discs, which is what I need, that's why acrules has nothing to do with it.